# Array has more values than expected

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a simple program that declares an integer array, a size for it, allocates memory for it based on size, initializes the elements, and then prints out every initialized element in the array. However, the output is not what I am expecting and I can't seem to find any documentation to explain it. I'll post the code and output below:

```
#include <iostream>

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int* a;
    int size = 4;

    a = new int[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i + 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        if(a[i])
        {
            std::cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << a[i] << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

- Output:
- a[0] = 1
- a[1] = 2
- a[2] = 3
- a[3] = 4
- a[4] = -33686019
- a[5] = -1414812757
- a[6] = -1414812757
- a[7] = -17891602

Comment: pointer a is not initialized correctly which results in undefined behavior. Newly allocated memory for pointer a is not freed. For statement needs to be corrected too. Many many mistakes that need to be fixed.

Comment: I declared my pointer a, later defined it as a new array of a size of 4 (taking advantage of C++11 I believe), and set the values for the expected elements. I realize I didn't delete a, which was just laziness on my part. If you can explain your reasoning for why you think a is initialized incorrectly, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: not initializing pointer a correctly will give you a uninitialized pointer/wild pointer with undefined behavior or segmentation fault error. Solution: initialize pointer a to null or 0 before allocating new memory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; ; i++)
```

When does your loop end?!?!? Your second condition in `for` (the testing expression) is evaluated as `true` (at least as long as `i<4`). You need

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
```

Otherwise it may break anytime after `i>=4`, but not before, since all components of `a` are non zero for `i<4` (`a[i] = i + 1;`), and after `i==4` you have undefined behaviour as you didn't allocate enough memory for `a`.

Also, `main` should return `int` according to the `C++` standard.

PS: For a vast majority of simple examples, most of the time you don't even need a debugger, just simulate in your head, or on a piece of paper, what the program is doing, line by line, and you'll catch the error.

Comment: I just had it loop until it has an issue with the array, so it breaks from the loop when that happens.

Comment: In response to your edit, the second for loop iterates 9 times before exiting the loop and continuing to system("PAUSE"). Also, my main() is a void type, which is allowed in a Win32 console application.

Comment: @Aaron it is allowed by Microsoft. Microsoft is not the author of the C++ standard. If you want your software to be portable, please be standard compliant. And your loop loops 9 times because it happens that after the 8-th element the memory contains a 0 at that point. This is however undefined behaviour, and I'll bet my life that on other platform/computer your loop will run more or less than 9 times.

Comment: @Aaron for example, check http://ideone.com/ekGB7J It happens that on ideone, at the time I'm writing this, your loop runs only for 4 times, as the memory after the 4th element happens to be zero. However this is not at all a guarantee, and you should never ever build a software component assuming that the heap is zero-initialized.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Now my question is how is it that undefined behavior can occur? As in why doesn't it cause an error (sorry if the answer seems obvious)

Comment: @Aaron, that's a fair question. Unlike Java and other langs, which checks array bounds etc at runtime, C/C++ was designed with high speed/performance in mind, so it allows the programmer to do almost anything, without checking possible runtime errors (such as exceeding the allocated memory etc). These checks take time, and C/C++ trusts the programmer :) So, the standard says that whenever you have such a situation, you have "undefined behaviour", meaning that anything can happen (basically the one who wrote the compiler is responsible for these cases, and can do whatever he/she/they like).

Comment: @Aaron, in a nutshell, do not expect C/C++ to catch runtime errors (not syntactic errors) for you. You should always check bounds/pointers/etc, or make absolutely sure that they are valid. This is the price to pay for high speed/performance.

Comment: Right, I suppose I'm used to this being handled for me in C#. I will keep this in mind